# In QGIS, how to filter overlay_intersects by attribute value?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-expression

I have two layers: point and linestring.

**Point:**

| ID | color_point | name_point |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | ? |
| 2 | green | ? |
| 3 | blue | ? |
| 4 | red | ? |
| 5 | brown | ? |

**Line:**

| ID | color_line | name_line |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red, green | fire, grass |
| 2 | blue | water |
| 3 | red, brown | house, earth |

At the end of a linestring there is at least one point.
For each point I want to get the appropriate attribute value *name* from the table of the linestring layer.
The tables are linked by the attribute *color*.
If several points lie at the end of a linestring, then several *color* elements with corresponding *name* values are listed in the attribute table of the line layer. Each attrinutes are ordered.
Since a point is always on the endpoint of a linestring, I can use the overlay_within function.

How I expect it to work (but returns NULL):

`overlay_intersects('linestring', name_line, color_line IS "color_point")[0]`

How it works testwise:

`overlay_intersects('linestring', name_line, color_line IS 'red')[0]`

In my example the points 1 and 2 lie at the end of line 1, point 3 at the end of line 2 and the points 4 and 5 share coordinates with the endpoint of line 3.
So in the end the point attribute table should look like this:

| ID | color_point | name_point |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | fire |
| 2 | green | grass |
| 3 | blue | water |
| 4 | red | house |
| 5 | brown | earth |

Comment: In your expression your have `name_line`, but in your tables, the attributes are named otherwise. You also have `color_line`, but no attribute of this name. This is quite confusing. If you already post your attribute tables, it should be consistent with your expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to use attribute fieldnames consistently - in your initial question, you used other fieldnames in your expression than you showed in your attribute table. Still, your use case is a bit more complex as your line layer has two values in each field. So you have to work with arrays and maps to achieve what you want.

Use this expression (see below for explanation):

```
map_get (
    hstore_to_map (
        array_to_string (
            with_variable (
                'len',
                array_length (string_to_array (overlay_intersects ('line', color_line)[0]))-1,
                array_foreach (
                    generate_series (0,@len),
                        string_to_array (array_to_string (overlay_intersects ('line', color_line)))[@element]
                        || '=>' || 
                        string_to_array (array_to_string (overlay_intersects ('line', name)))[@element] 
                )
            )
        )
    ), 
    color_point
)
```

[image]

Explanation:

1. Get `color_line` and `name` values from separately the line layer with `overlay_intersects()`
2. Convert this to a string and back to an array: like this, the string `'red,green'` is converted to an array with two elements: `[ 'red', 'green' ]` (and `'fire,grass'` to `[ 'fire', ' grass' ]`)
3. Concatenate the two values for  `color_line` and `name` with `'=>'` as a delimiter in between: the array becomes like `'red=>fire'`
4. With `array_foreach()`, repat this for each element to get an array like this: `[ 'red=>fire', 'green=> grass' ]`
5. Convert to a string with `array_to_string()` to get `'red=>fire,green=> grass'`
6. Convert this to a map (key:value pair) with `hstore_to_map()` to get: `{ 'green': 'grass', 'red': 'fire' }`
7. Use `map_get()` to get the value from the map that has the key that corresponds to your `color_point` value.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!